# form_for not rendering to view but is generating html correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have the following form in my view:

```
<%= form_for @new_home, :url => {:controller => "homes", :action => "create"} do |f| %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
       <%= f.label :name, "Home Name:" %><br />
       <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
       <%= f.submit("Add New Home", :class => "green_button") %>
<% end %>
```

And controller:

```
def main
    @new_home = Home.new
end
```

The generated html is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/homes/create" class="new_home" id="new_home" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="lyvJq8FmFoOvzi7LYNhkrY8t9WI9phtBlNdGvMOFoF8=" />
    <input id="home_user_id" name="home[user_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <label for="home_name">Home Name:</label><br />
    <input id="home_name" name="home[name]" size="30" type="text" />
    <input class="green_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add New Home" />
</form>
```

For some reason i cannot see the form being displayed in my view. There is no error generated. All i see is a blank page with no form. I have not applied any jquery or css to hide the form. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the div field and action classes. See below.

```
<%= form_for @new_home, :url => {:controller => "homes", :action => "create"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name, "Home Name:" %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
   <%= f.submit("Add New Home", :class => "green_button") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work!

Comment: Actually the div should not matter. Your form looks just like mine otherwise. Not sure what's going on here... I'll take a look at it again later.